# How to show ads at specific points using ExoPlayer's IMA extension?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using `ExoPlayer 2.7.3` with IMA extension. I have to show ads at certain intervals. I have managed to integrate the `AdsLoader` and `AdsMediaSource`. I am receiving and displaying the ads. But the ads are only appearing at the beginning of the movie. How do I make the ads to be shown at the points when I want them to (for eg. at every 30 minutes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you are using the IMA extension with the ImaAdsLoader or your custom implementation of AdsLoader which is part of the core library (no IMA extension required):

**Using IMA ad tags**

If you are using the IMA extension you need to create an the `ImaAdsLoader` with an ad tag from IMA/DoubleClick ([sample tags](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/tags)):

```
new ImaAdsLoader(this, adTagUri);
```

The tag points to a VMAP/VAST file which defines when the ads are played. So with this solution you can't tell the player the position of the ads programmatically. Instead all this information is loaded from the ad tag.

**Custom AdsLoader implementation**

You can create your own implementation of `AdsLoader` which you can pass to the constructor or the AdsMediaSource instead of the IMA version. The `AdsMediaSource` will then call the `attachPlayer(player, eventListener, adUiViewGroup)` method of your ads loader. The second param is an `AdsLoader.EventListener` with which the `AdsMediaSource` can be notified about the state of your ads loader.

If, at this moment, you already have the information of the ads and at what position to play them, you can just call the listener once when the player is attached:

```
    // create playback state with two ad groups (at 0 and 30 seconds)
    AdPlaybackState adPlaybackState = new AdPlaybackState(0, 30 * C.MICROS_PER_SECOND);
    // add the uri of the first ad of the first ad group
    adPlaybackState = adPlaybackState.withAdUri(0, 0, mp4UriWithAd);
    // add the uri of the first ad of the second ad group
    adPlaybackState = adPlaybackState.withAdUri(1, 0, mp4UriWithAd);
    // add the uri of the second ad of the second ad group
    adPlaybackState = adPlaybackState.withAdUri(1, 1, mp4UriWithAd);
    // pass to AdsLoader.EventListener 
    eventListener.onAdPlaybackState(adPlaybackState);
```

However, it might happen that you need to load ad information from the network first. In this case you can just update the playback state when ever you retrieved new information about ads. Just call `onAdPlaybackState` again for an update.

Comment: Hi I followed your ans, but from `create your own implementation of AdsLoader` , what exactly do you suggest for Ad handling ? I tried reading `ImaAdsLoader` implementation, but couldn't understand how is it able to show vmap ads, like how is it running ads at correct time intervals when exoplayer does not expose elapsed times? I would like to make some AdLoader like that only, but with vast ads, i.e `MyAdsLoader` would take manual time intervals(0,15, etc) ,but no vast tags. Whenever the time interval comes(eg at 15th sec), it should fire an event requesting for VastAdTag Url from observer

Comment: Hi, I am using IMA and I could not find any listeners for knowing when the ads is loaded. Can you please help?

Comment: this is brilliant and exactly the use case we have. however im new to Exoplayer and from the code snippets above can't piece together how to configure everything to ensure the ads play at our nominated times. would it be possible to provide a more complete code example above ?

Comment: I have same requirements as mentioned in question but unable to do it with IMA extension. I am developing an android tv app and using exoplayer for hls. Can you please give any custom loader implementation code example? Because I have no idea about custom adloader. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did anyone found the solution?