# How to implement custom AdsLoader to play ads using exoplayer and AdsMediaSource?

Tags: android, ads, exoplayer

This is in line with the question below :
[How to show ads at specific points using ExoPlayer's IMA extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871348/how-to-show-ads-at-specific-points-using-exoplayers-ima-extension/52578548?noredirect=1#comment92092195_52578548)

I followed the answer given by marcbaechinger however it is not working for me. It doesn't even play the main video if I add the adPlaybackState  as mentioned in the answer. Do I need to do anything additional? 
Anyone has success in playing ads preroll, midroll using the above method?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that IMA extension is only good if you are thinking about using google video ad sdk, if you have you own ads that you want the preroll, midroll ads, you have to implement you own logic. [Tubiplayer](https://github.com/Tubitv/TubiPlayer) is a internal project that my company decide to open source, feel free to see how we implement the pre-roll and mid-roll ads

Comment: Thanks Allen, I am not using Google IMA but have tried to written my custom AdsLoader and created AdsMediaSource passing the same to it.

Comment: As explained in the answer by "marcbaechinger "  however it is not working for me and the Ad is not playing neither the main video. I had a look at the code of Tubiplayer. Can I see  below classes : MediaHelper and MediaModel  ? I am using Exoplayer, have the ads url and the positions (e.g  0s 30s ) where to display ads.

Comment: Implementing you own pre-roll and mid-roll ads is very complicated, its involves stateful transitions, and managing and releasing resources. On [Tubiplayer](https://github.com/Tubitv/TubiPlayer), the only thing you need to make pro-roll and mid-roll is to change 1 line of code:  https://github.com/Tubitv/TubiPlayer/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/tubitv/media/di/PlayerModuleDefault.java#L133 .  In this class, instead of  callBack.onCuePointReceived(null), you just pass in array of cuepoints that you want to show(in millseconds), there are some test ads. After that change, just run it.

Comment: Hi Allen I downloaded but could not build and getting below exception. Looks like related to build.gradle                                                                      Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type

Comment: eh, it might be that you are using wrong gradle setting, go to gradle setting in preference, and make sure you select "Use default gradle wrapper" to fetch your gradle version instead

Comment: Thanks Yes the upgrade to gradle version was causing this issue.Now it got resolved however I am getting compiler error in  class  
 RealActivity                                                                   
 error: cannot find symbol variable DaggerFsmComponentReal. Am I missing any library folder?

Comment: oops DaggerFsmComponentReal this was a spelling mistake the class name is DaggerFsmComonentReal Thannks the app is running now

Comment: great, Keeps in mind DaggerFsmComonentReal was auto generated code by dagger, whenever you run into problem, just do a rebuild, it will resolve the problem

Comment: Hi @allengotstuff . Tubiplayer looks very intimidating with so many modules/classes/dependencies, so less documentation and so less updates. If you are a maintainer of that module, can you share some insights on how that library is actually working? Also let me know how its handling Vast Ad loading and running, when I pass 3 time intervals and 1 vast ad tag for each time interval to it. The last time I checked, exoplayer didn't exposed any video playback control , Like i cannot possibly pause the video at exactly 30 seconds from start, and show ad, there was no such time tracker

Comment: Hi @anshsachdeva, you are right, exoplayer doesn't have such tracker for pause the video at certain time, and show ads. However, whenever you are playing a video, we wrote a listener to give current progress update every second, https://github.com/Tubitv/TubiPlayer/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/tubitv/media/fsm/listener/CuePointMonitor.java , so you can think about now tubiplayer is smart enough to know when to play for a ad if you just tell the player a list of array of timelines