# Play Linear Inline Ads Every 5 Min in ExoPlayer with IMA extension

Tags: android, ads, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am Very Beginner in Exoplayer with IMA, I am creating Video player with Exoplayer and IMA extension. I Created Exoplayer using https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/client-side
Its Play ads only one time. But I want to play Linear Inline ads every 5 mins. I tried [How to show ads at specific points using ExoPlayer's IMA extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871348/how-to-show-ads-at-specific-points-using-exoplayers-ima-extension)

```
    Uri adTagUri = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.ad_tag_url));
    AdPlaybackState adPlaybackState = new AdPlaybackState(0, 300 * C.MICROS_PER_SECOND);
     // add the uri of the first ad of the first ad group
    adPlaybackState = adPlaybackState.withAdUri(0, 0, adTagUri);
    // add the uri of the first ad of the second ad group
    adPlaybackState = adPlaybackState.withAdUri(1, 0, adTagUri);
    // add the uri of the second ad of the second ad group
    adPlaybackState = adPlaybackState.withAdUri(1, 1, adTagUri);
```

Got error in  eventListener.onAdPlaybackState(adPlaybackState);

My Lib implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-ima:2.11.1'
MyCode

MainActivity.java

```
    private PlayerView playerView;
    private SimpleExoPlayer player;
    private ImaAdsLoader adsLoader;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        adsLoader = new ImaAdsLoader(this, Uri.parse(getString(R.string.ad_tag_url)));
    }
    private void releasePlayer() {
        adsLoader.setPlayer(null);
        playerView.setPlayer(null);
        player.release();
        player = null;
    }
    private void initializePlayer() {
        // Create a SimpleExoPlayer and set it as the player for content and ads.
        player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        adsLoader.setPlayer(player);

        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
                new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name)));
        ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory mediaSourceFactory =
                new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory);
        MediaSource mediaSource =
                mediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.content_url)));
        AdsMediaSource adsMediaSource =
                new AdsMediaSource(mediaSource, dataSourceFactory, adsLoader, playerView);
        player.prepare(adsMediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }
```

Help me to Complete Code

Comment: Do you have any update on this? I'm also trying to add ads in the middle of the content, tried this but didn't worked.

Comment: I didn't get any updates @SouravRoy

Comment: please post If you get answer

Comment: @Ajith May i kow where i get this ad tag url? testing ads url working fine for me.

Comment: I got the ad tag URL from Github

Comment: Can you complete my code???